# JQuery grid is selecting only first two rows when clicked on header check box

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

When I click on header check box on the jqgrid, it is selecting only first two rows of the grid. Not sure what is happening. Multiselect property is set to true.

```
     Jquery library version is 1.4.2 and jqGrid version is 4.1.2
```

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you have jQuery version 4.1.2. ?

Comment: I am sorry, Jquery library version is 1.4.2 and jqGrid is 4.1.2

Comment: I think your are using 1.4.1.2 right?

Comment: @user1614862 use the latest jQuery version when ever possible and show us the code for selecting checkboxex

Comment: I cannot migrate to the latest jquery library. My project is very big and old. There is no specific code written for selecting multiple rows. I have just set multiselect as true while creating the grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that you filled the grid with wrong ids. The problem is that jqGrid **require** that every row of the grid (every `<tr>`) have unique `id` attribute. The input data of should contains `id` information. On the other side if you would use data with **duplicate ids** then you can have effects like you described in your answer.

So I would recommend you to examine the values of `id` attributes of `<tr>` elements of the grid. If you would see that the `id` of the 3-d row for example is the same as the id of the first or the second row then it would explain the problem.

In any way I would strictly recommend you to include JavaScript code and some test data which should explain what you do. Guessing what you could do by showing the picture only is not really effective.

Comment: Yeah...it looks like something to do with IDs only. Actually my ids come from database. Except one id, remaining all are coming as null values. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @user1614862: I'm glad that I could help you. You are welcome!